# Stop camera from seeing inside objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new to Unity and to the Vuforia SDK. How do I stop the camera from passing through an object and "seeing" the inside when the user gets very close to the target?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the reason this happens is because the camera is not a physics object, so it has no collisions.  So, what you need to do is create an empty and give it a box or sphere collider (sphere is probably better in most cases), you can then set it's position to the same as the camera and parent the camera to the empty.  This way, the camera will get the collision effects of it's parent empty.

If after this the camera can still "see" through the object, you may need to set near clipping planes to 0.1.

You might also be able to give the camera itself a collider sphere or box directly (without using an empty), but I have not tested this.

There is a similar question on answers.unity3d.com -> [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/473917/how-to-prevent-camera-from-moving-through-meshes.html)

Comment: Oddly this doesn't seem to be working for me. I had already decreased the near clipping planes (down to 0.01) which helped in that the user now has to get really close to the object before walking through it. But encasing the camera in a collider seems to have no effect. Things I've tried: Sphere and box colliders on the empty Game Object (with the ARCamera as the child) with varying radiuses / sizes, Rigidbodies on the game object I'm seeing inside of and / or the camera's parent game object, and applying a script to the objects and seeing if onCollsionEnter, etc. are called and they aren't.

Comment: When I get home I'll give it a try and see if I can duplicate the issue.